# Version 53.0.0.0 of cefSharp subprocess gives error

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am getting an error when launching a demo app using nugget version 53 of CefSharp.wpf.

However, when pulling the code from github which is on version 55 (not stable), the demo app works.

The error seems to be with the CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe where the faulting module is libcef.dll.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: It might be https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1819 Really just guessing as you've not provided much detail

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What information do you require? As soon as I run my app I get an exception dialog saying libcef.dll is the faulting module. No web page is rendered at this time. Do you need to see the exact error?

Comment: Did you read the issue I linked?

Comment: You need to give more details like if you have all the necessary dlls and other binaries in your output directory